# how to get the last incoming transaction before date

Tags: transactions, blocks

I need to get the incoming transaction before the date currently i use

```
https://web3api.io/api/v1/addresses/0xaD4b04Df17f2d35F81771Fa124dBD94E33587F4c/transactions?to=0xaD4b04Df17f2d35F81771Fa124dBD94E33587F4c&size=1
```

The above API returns recent incoming transaction .I want incoming transaction of account before 3 Nov. In that case how do i get that incoming transaction.

Comment: Check out the Graph protocol which will allow you to do this: https://thegraph.com/.

Answer (score 1):

You can list the transactions as you are doing and then filter the results by timestamp. november 3 of 2018 is `1520809200`, so search in the transactions results for all the transactions with `timestamp < 1520809200`

You can get the list of transactions of a particular address using [etherscan API](https://etherscan.io/apis#accounts). The method is: **Get a list of 'Normal' Transactions By Address**

This will remove the need to loop across blocks. You will just need to get the key timestamp of the list of json objects returned by the api.

This should be fast.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jamine it is helpful . Already i did like this. It is time consuming . so i search for APIs

Comment: Can you tell me what tool are you using for this, if this is one in a particular address it should not be an issue for an average laptop using python

Comment: for this now i am using web3 . it takes much time . i take blocks then loop and check timestamp and "to address"

Comment: I just updated the answer, take a look. etherscan allows you to get a list of the transaction by address then you just look for the timestamp, so you do not need to check in every single block.

Comment: Thank you @jaime , it provide result .. it is possible to get the single call without condition and loop.

Comment: @Sammu I do not understand if you are asking or telling me. If this helped you please accept the answer.

Comment: I am asking @jaime , your answer is working but it needs loop and condition statements to find the transaction, i ask is any alternate API  available  to get the transaction at the time of API call . is any API available like that?

Comment: Not that I know, this is too specific to be included in a general API.